# Using userscript to click on a td from a table

Tags: javascript, userscripts

It looks like a radio button but it's actually just a td. I know how to select a regular radio button, but how do I select a td?

$('input[value="no"]').click();

---

This is what the table code look like:

```
<table align="center" width="90%" class="hoverTable">
                <tr style="height: 50px">
                    <td width="85%"><span title="Commonsense about social situations. For example: situations that involve other people and evoke emotions of anger, laughter etc." class="tt">Social Commonsense</span>?</td>
                    <td align="center" width="8%">
                        YES
                    </td>
                </tr>

                <tr style="height: 50px">
                    <td><span title="Commonsense about the physical world. E.g. cars are smaller than garages." class="tt">Physical Commonsense</span>?</td>
                    <td align="center">
                        NO
                    </td>
                </tr>

                <tr style="height: 50px">
                    <td><span title="Commonsense about the biological world. For example: plants are fixed in location, people need to eat food to survive etc." class="tt">Biological Commonsense</span>?</td>
                    <td align="center">
                        NO
                    </td>
                </tr>

                <tr style="height: 50px">
                    <td><span title="Commonsense about how the world works. For example: countries have states, babies crawl before walking etc." class="tt">Man-Made Constructs Commonsense</span>?</td>
                    <td align="center">
                        YES
                    </td>
                </tr>

                <tr style="height: 50px">
                    <td><span title="The order in which events occur in time. For example: you need to turn ignition on before driving a car" class="tt">Temporal Order</span> of events?</td>
                    <td align="center">
                        NO
                    </td>
                </tr>

                <tr style="height: 50px">
                    <td><span title="Commonsense about which agent / person performs the required action. For example: If Person1 apologizes to Person2, Person2 accepts the apology, not Person1." class="tt">Agent-Action Commonsense</span>?</td>
                    <td align="center">
                        NO
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr style="height: 50px">
                    <td><span title="Commonsense about where certain events can happen. For example: people typically eat in a restaurant, play in the park etc." class="tt">Spatial / Location Commonsense</span>?</td>
                    <td align="center">
                        NO
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
```

Comment: show **more** code ... :/

Comment: @MrJ I just shown the table code

Comment: @frosty can you be clearer about what you want? Like do you want something to happen if you click on the `<td>`?

Comment: @AniketG I want it to select the radio button. I didn't write the website, I'm just using userscript to select something on their website.

Comment: `align="center"`  doesn't exist anymore in html ..

Comment: @MrJ I didn't write this website...Just the userscript...

Answer (score 1):

I suppose you use jQuery ?

```js
   $('.hoverTable td').click(function() {
    var inVal =  $(this).html();
    var newVal = inVal=='NO'?'YES':'NO';
    $(this).html(newVal)
   });
```